# integrating redis into serverless

Tags: redis, node-redis, serverless-framework

I am looking at integrating a caching service with serverless.

I have decided to go with redis. However through reading through the [npm redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis), it seems that you are required to call `client.quit()` after completing the request.

The way serverless seems to work is that the instance is spawned, and then deleted when not in use. So I was wondering if there was a way to quit the redis connection when the serverless instance is being deleted.

Or whether I just have to actually just start a connection on every request, and quit the connection before each request finishes.

I was hoping I could do it on the app state, instead of request state, that way I wont have to spawn so many connections.

Answer (score 0):

No. A connection could be reused. It does not need to start a new connection on every request.

If you use the `redis.creatClient()` to create a connection, you could use this connection always in your app. And it has reconnect mechanism if the connection is broken. So in your app development, you do not need to care the connection problem, just get a global connection and always use it.

Comment: so I do not need to call `client.quit()` at all ? 
From what I read if u dont call this, it doesnt close the connection.

Comment: yes, it will not close the connection if you don't call the client.quit(). But why you call the client.quit(), your app is running, and still need this client to send the command to redis, you still need this connection. So when your app is running, it hold an connection to redis, whenever you want to send command to redis, use this client to do it. if you create a client for every request, it will be a big cost.

Comment: You should set the client to global variable, and everywhere in your code could use it.

Comment: Serverless will automatically close the instance, when there are no requests being sent. 
This is why I need to close it. The lambda functionality will spin up an instance when a request comes, but after some time, it will stop it.

Comment: when your instance is running,  just using a connection to handle all the redis command request, when your instance is closing, close the connection.

Comment: that is my question, how do I know when it is closing ? I only know when the request is starting and ending, not when the instance is starting and ending.

Comment: IS there something like global state or variable in this serverless framework.